# How to customize Google Maps in order to get rid of the 3D buildings effect?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my Google Map (Google Maps API v3):

```
var mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7607793, -111.8910474),
   zoom: 8,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   tilt: 0
};
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, mapOptions);
```

I want to "flatten" the buildings, and get rid of the 3D effect.

As an example, I would like the buildings layout below (on the right), to be shown flat the same way that the "indoor" part of the map (the left side).

[image]

I am able to get rid of the buildings completely, customizing the style of the map and  setting lightness to 100%:

```
this.map.set('styles', [
   {
      featureType: 'landscape',
      elementType: 'geometry',
      stylers: [                    
         { lightness: 100 }
      ]
   }
]);
```

which obviously is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your map options, try setting `mapMaker:false`

Comment: Thanks Duncan - it does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate 3D buildings when creating a new map in Google's "Map Management" tab on Google Maps Platform.

You must select "raster" and not "vector" when creating the map.

Answer (score -2):

```
    featureType: 'landscape.man_made',
        elementType: 'geometry',
        stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
   }
]);
```

Comment: Could you add a brief description of what your solution does?

Comment: That removes the building layout entirely.